# Calculation of Rated Power for IGBT Module

Tags: power, power-electronics, converter, semiconductors, igbt

For an IGBT module with the following characteristics, how can we calculate the rated power? I mean how much is the rated power for this module?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "rated power"?  It's rated for a specific power dissipation, but I assume that's not what you mean.  If you want to know how much power a circuit built using this IGBT module can handle -- that depends so heavily on so many factors other than the characteristics of the IGBT itself that any claims would be nearly meaningless.

Comment: These are the maximum rating. Ratings you should **not** operate at.